# Trouble parsing a delimited string in php

Tags: php, regex, csv

I'm extracting values from a delimited string that usually has the form:

valueA|valueB|valueC

Where '|' is a delimiter.

In this simple case, I'm just using explode to extract the separate values. However, sometimes the string will have brackets, where any characters including '|' can be between those brackets. For example:

valueA|valueB[any characters including '|']|valueC

How can I parse this string to reliably extract the three separate values (valueA, valueB[any characters including '|'], valueC). I'm pretty sure a regex is my best bet, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are all non-delimiter pipes guaranteed to be within square brackets? Can square brackets be nested within square brackets (i.e., `valueB[some[stuff]]`)? Is it possible to change the data so that each data element is enclosed in quotes or something (i.e., `"valA"|"valB[1|2]"|"valC"`)? (My guess is no on that last one, but it'd make things much easier. :-)

Comment: @Wiseguy Actually yes to all three. I would just change the delimiter, but I will have the same problem regardless of which character(s) I use..

Comment: @Mark - if you have control over the format, why not just use an established format like CSV?

Comment: @thetaiko Exactly why I asked -- to see if he could simply use `fgetcsv()`/`str_getcsv()`.

Comment: @thetaiko Perhaps I'm missing the point you and @Wiseguy are making but aren't CSVs just delimited strings? Also, perhaps its helpful to mention that although I have control over the format, the string is being passed to php from javascript...

Comment: Yes, CSV is just a delimited string, but when you enclose the values in quotes between the delimiters, that accounts for having your delimiter character in the values. That's how spreadsheets work -- delimiter is usually a comma or tab, but fields can still have commas/tabs in them because they're enclosed in quotes. Those quotes are part of the accepted CSV format, and PHP's CSV functions recognize them.

Comment: @Wiseguy. That's perfect. I didn't know that CSVs worked that way. That's exactly what I'll do. Thanks!

Comment: @Wiseguy You should submit that info as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @Mark Brown - You've got a good answer via @Wiseguy.  Another option would be to pass a JSON encoded object to PHP.

Comment: I agree. I was just thinking the same thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the comments to the question, you have the ability to change the format. That being the case, one small adjustment will have you rolling. Since it's character-delimited, you're essentially working with a CSV file. Conventionally, CSV functionality allows you to enclose the data values in quotes between the delimiters. That way, if your delimiter character occurs within a piece of data, it will be parsed simply as part of the data string and not mistaken for a delimiter.

That's how spreadsheets work -- the delimiter is usually a comma or tab, but fields can still have commas/tabs in them because they're enclosed in quotes. Those quotes are part of the standard CSV format, and PHP's CSV functions recognize them.

As a simple illustration, your old strings:

```
valueA|valueB|valueC
valueA|valueB[any characters including '|']|valueC
```

would then be this:

```
"valueA"|"valueB"|"valueC"
"valueA"|"valueB[any characters including '|']"|"valueC"
```

See how the StackOverflow syntax highlighter catches that above? :-)

There are PHP functions for both reading and writing CSV formats like this.

Writing CSV from an array of fields: [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/fputcsv) (to a file descriptor)
Reading CSV into an array: [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) (from a file) or [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) (from a string, new in 5.3)

Default assumes that the delimiter is a comma and enclosure is a double quote, but you can optionally specify any character (such as '|') for those tasks.

Comment: One small note - if a `"` appears inside a field, it should be doubled.  `valueA|value"B"|valueC` => `"valueA"|"value""B"""|"valueC"`